# using swiftmailer to send bulk email

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm using swiftmailer to send emails to users when someone registers on my site.
When i want to send out an email to them members i used the same function but just did a while loop of all my members to send an email to all of them.

The problem im having is this times out at around 120 seconds when its only 10-20% the way through my members table. Whats the fastest way round fixing this? Can i add a sleep or???

The code is

```
<?php
include ('functions.php');
connect();
require_once 'lib/swift_required.php';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT member_id, email, firstname FROM members")
or die ("Error - Something went wrong.");

$i = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo nl2br("memberid = $row[member_id]");
    $useremail = $row['email'];
    $user_name = $row['firstname'];
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('my smtp server', 25);

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
        ->setSubject('my subject')
        ->setFrom(array('noreply@mydomain.com' => 'mydomain'))
        ->setTo(array("$useremail" =>" $user_name"))
        ->setBody(
           '<html>' .
           '<head></head>' .
           '<body>' .
                my email body
           '</body>' .
           '</html>',
           'text/html'
            );

    if ($mailer->send($message)){
        mail("registrations@mydomain.com", "ok", "email sent to '$useremail'", "Sent ok");
    }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: if sending more than a couple of emails i would always put the task in to the background so the user does not to wait. same for anything that takes more than a couple of secounds

Comment: so to create a 'que' for instance? is there any documentation on how to do this?

Comment: yup, background tasks can run forever, foreground will time out depending on your settings, and you should never make the user wait for than a couple of seconds.

Comment: Any reason why you’re not using a third-party provider like MailChimp or Campaign Monitor which are built to send mass email campaigns?

Answer (score 0):

You should use CRON jobs (linux) or scheduled tasks (windows) to run the php script of sending email every X seconds.

Every PHP process has its max execution time, you can raise it, but that will not solve you problem when user list will get even bigger.